# rsync causing errors after sync

Tags: rsync

When I run the `rsync` command to push my files to production, sometimes - not always, and it's very rare - after the sync has completed, we are getting errors within our production environment.

The `rsync` command is;

```
rsync -avzO --exclude=*.git --exclude=*.log /var/www/html/ver_1/api root@production.local:/var/www/html/ver_1
```

I've confirmed the following;

- Production and test environment settings (PHP and Apache) mirror one another
- The issue *has* to be with the `rsync` command because when I manually copy the files (using [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)) there is no issue - so it's not a code fault.
- We're syncing from a CentOS machine to a CentOS machine (if that makes any difference)

**Questions**

- What could be causing the issue?

  - Why would it only happen sometimes (2/3 times out of 25-ish)
- How can I resolve it, or minimize the occurrence?

#### Edit

`PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Cannot redeclare class api\lib\classapitools\apitools in /var/www/html/ver_1/api/index.php on line 42`

- I've copied the index.php file from test to production, but it didn't fix it.
- Re-ran the rsync command, and it didn't fix it.
- Then I copied all the files manually and it worked. I debugged the whole application, but it didn't return anything insightful about the error (I know why the error is there (in a general sense), but the `rsync` seemed to have FUBAR'd the whole application until a manual sync)

Comment: What are the "errors" you get in production?

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Cannot redeclare class api\lib\classapitools\apitools in /var/www/html/ver_1/api/index.php on line 42` I've copied the `index.php` file from test to production, but it didn't fix it. Re-ran the `rsync` command, and it didn't fix it. Then I copied the files manually and it worked. I debugged the whole application, but it didn't return anything insightful about the error (I know why the error is there (in a general sense), but the rsync seemed to have FUBAR'd the whole application until a manual sync)

Comment: Do you restart the server/app as part of the update procedure? The error message suggests that might be what you're missing, to ensure a clean environment started from the new version of the code. I am not a PHP developer, though, so I may have it wrong...

Comment: We don't restart the server as part of the update procedure as there is no need and the downtime is unwanted - even though it was down for a while, I didn't attempt it. The `rsync` only updated a small amount of files (although they were core files). I just don't understand why when replacing the whole code manually fixed the issue, and `rsync`'ing killed it. (You don't compile the PHP application like you would with an app made in C)

Comment: Try enabling logging in your `rsync` invocations. Might show up any odd behaviour from `rsync`. The problem sounds like it might be caused by two processes wanting to access one of the updated files at the same time - the server reading it to serve a request, `rsync` to write an updated version. You could try using `--blocking-io` to see if it helps.

Comment: Some great suggestions @D_Bye - I'll experiment with that later on today, thanks!

Comment: Do you have symlinks in the directories that are being rsynced? You might have to use the options `-K` or `-k` to copy the symlinks. Please open the `man` page of `rsync` and look for symlinks.

Comment: @Sree A good thought, but no symlinks are expected to be sync'd

Comment: @hd, hey why are the slashes in the error backslashes? Did you develop the code in a Windows machine?

Comment: @Sree Nope, those are [class namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem most likely lies in your use of the `-a` flag on rsync.
That is equivalent to a set of other options, including `-t`, which preserves the modification time of the files.

As you don't restart the application on the target machine, you are now dependent on that machine rereading some or all of those files or not, depending on the application and whether these files are observed as being changed.

You try to use `-rlpgoD` instead of `-a`. The "wrong" timestamp of files transferred in the previous rsync (but not in the current), should not cause any troubles, `rsync` is smart enough to notice that the content is the same even if the timestamps are not.

If you had been using the `--in-place` option you would probably encounter more problems.

Comment: So I've ran the `rsync` scripts a while (from development to test), and using your suggestion the issue hasn't come up again - Thanks!